# Problema con jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Buen día. Pasa lo siguiente:

Quiero tomar los valor de un registro en `Mysql`, el problema está cuando pincho sobre otro, se abre el mismo que pinche de primero. Digamos que pinche **1** que tenga como **id = 1**, si pincho el que tiene **id=4** me muestra otra vez el **id=1**. No se por qué.

Este es el formulario para actualizar:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalM" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm " role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Actualizar Cliente</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="frmClientesU">
                        <input type="text" hidden="" id="idclienteU" name="idclienteU"> 
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="nombreU" name="nombreU">
                        <label>Apellido</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="apellidosU" name="apellidosU">
                        <label>Direccion</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="direccionU" name="direccionU">
                        <label>Correo</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="emailU" name="emailU">
                        <label>Telefono</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="telefonoU" name="telefonoU">
                        <label>N° Cedula</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="rfcU" name="rfcU">

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnActualizarCliente">Guardar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function agregaDatosCliente(idcliente){

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:"idcliente="+idcliente,
                url:"../procesos/clientes/obtenDatosCliente.php",
                success:function(m){

                    dato=jQuery.parseJSON(m);
                $('#idclienteU').val(dato['id_cliente']);
                $('#nombreU').val(dato['nombre']);
                $('#apellidosU').val(dato['apellido']);
                $('#direccionU').val(dato['direccion']);
                $('#emailU').val(dato['email']);
                $('#telefonoU').val(dato['telefono']);
                $('#rfcU').val(dato['rfc']);

                }

            });
        }
```

Esta con un id llamado `ModalM`

Esta es la tabla donde listo los clientes:

```
<?php 
require_once "../../clases/conexion.php";
$obj = new conectar();
$conexion =$obj->conexion();

$sql="SELECT id_cliente, 
                nombre,
                apellido,
                direccion,
                email,
                telefono,
                rfc 
        from clientes";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

 ?>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" style="text-align:center;">
    <caption><label>Clientes</label></caption>

    <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Apellido</td>
        <td>Direcion</td>
        <td>Correo</td>
        <td>Telefono</td>
        <td>N° Cedula</td>
        <td>Editar</td>
        <td>Eliminar</td>

    </tr>
    <?php 
    while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)):
     ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $ver[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ver[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ver[3]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ver[4]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ver[5]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ver[6]; ?></td>

        <td>
            <span class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalM" onclick="agregaDatosCliente('<?php echo $ver[0]; ?>')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">

                </span>
            </span>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <?php 
endwhile;

     ?>

</table>
</div>
```

Como ven tiene la función `onclick` con la cual llamo al formulario de actualizar a través de la función `agregaDatosCliente`. Hasta hay todo bien...

Esto es lo que uso para auto rellenar el formulario:

```
clientes.php
    public function obtenDatosCliente($idcliente){
            $mari=new conectar();
            $conexion=$mari->conexion();
            $sql= "SELECT id_cliente,nombre,apellido,direccion,email,telefono,rfc
            FROM clientes";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

            $mariana=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $datos=array(
                'id_cliente' => $mariana[0], 
                        'nombre' => $mariana[1],
                        'apellido' => $mariana[2],
                        'direccion' => $mariana[3],
                        'email' => $mariana[4],
                        'telefono' => $mariana[5],
                        'rfc' => $mariana[6]
                    );

            return $datos;

        }
```

Acá es donde hago el `json_encode`

```
datos.php
<?php 
require_once "../../clases/conexion.php";
require_once "../../clases/clientes.php";
$obj = new clientes();



echo json_encode($obj->obtenDatosCliente($_POST['idcliente']));
 ?>
```

Al dar al botón de actualizar me manda lo siguiente que puse en la imagen. Eso esta bien, sin embargo, cuando pincho en otro me manda el mismo id.

[image: 1]

Ahora bien, miré en inspeccionar y al darle click sobre uno veo que si esta tomando el id correcto, entonces no se que pasa

Espero que me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias.

Comment: Por lo que parece, en la sql de la función "obtenDatosCliente" necesitas especificar con where que idCliente quieres coger, ahora mismo te esta cogiendo la totalidad de la base por lo que solo te muestra el primer id. Sería una cosa así `SELECT id_cliente,nombre,apellido,direccion,email,telefono,rfc
            FROM clientes where id_cliente = '.$idcliente`

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo si era eso tenia todo bien excepto la comparativa en la consulta sql

Comment: @JairoRoderoVilla ¿podrías escribir una respuesta para que la pregunta no aparezca sin solución? Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano Por supuesto

Comment: Mariana, considera marcar la respuesta de @JairoRoderoVilla, activando la flecha gris a la izquierda de la misma, para que la pregunta no aparezca como sin resolver. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La comunicación es correcta, lo único que falta es especifcar en la query, con un where, que idCliente necesitas mostrar.

Quedaría un cosa así.

```
SELECT id_cliente,nombre,apellido,direccion,email,telefono,rfc FROM clientes where id_cliente = '.$idcliente
```

Si muestras todo tabla, tal y como lo estabas obteniendo solo te iba a mostrar el primer registro de la tabla